# Realm Sync Facebook Authentication not working

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to enable Facebook authentication in Realm Sync, but keep getting an error on login.

I have been using these guides:

1. https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/using-synced-realms/user-authentication/additional-providers#facebook
2. https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/self-hosted/customize/authentication/included-third-party-auth-providers/facebook-authentication

I have the Access Token provided by the Facebook API/SDK enabling me to log in/sign up a user.

When I use Realm's libraries to log in a user with the Facebook Access Token, I get an error stating the 'provider' parameter is invalid, but this parameter is defined by Realm's own classes.

I have successfully authenticated a user with an email & password so do I need to set up something else on Facebook/Realm Sync? It seems Facebook authentication just doesn't work in Realm Sync and the above help files are pretty useless.

**Authentication code**

```
func authenticateWithFacebook(facebookToken: String, completion: @escaping (RealmAuthenticationResult) -> ()) {
    let credentials = SyncCredentials.facebook(token: facebookToken)

    print("------FACEBOOK LOGIN-------")
    print("Token: \(facebookToken)")

    login(credentials) { (result, userId) in
        completion(result)
    }
}

private func login(_ credentials: SyncCredentials, completion: @escaping (RealmAuthenticationResult, String?) -> ()) {

    SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: RealmConnection.AUTH_URL, onCompletion: { (user, err) in
        if let _ = user {
            print("User has logged in/signed up")
            return completion(RealmAuthenticationResult.success(true), user?.identity)
        } else if let error = err {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return completion(RealmAuthenticationResult.failure(error), user?.identity)
        }
    })
}
```

**The error**

> Error Domain=io.realm.sync.auth Code=601 "Your request parameters did
>   not validate. provider: Invalid parameter 'provider'!;"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Your request parameters did not
>   validate. provider: Invalid parameter 'provider'!;}

**Other things I have tried**

I have tried directly instantiating the base provider class 'RLMIdentityProvider' and creating SyncCredentials with that, but no dice.

A workaround is to get the account information from the Facebook API/SDK and use the account's email to login/signup with a username/password setup. However, it seems to make Facebook authentication redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Realm Documentation link is outdated. See the 3.16.0 Documentation (or later) as a lot was changed.

At the moment Password, JWT & Firebase are the only auth options with Firebase Authentication being a very solid solution. Integrating Firebase is also covered in the Realm Documentation in the Using Sync'd Realms -> Authentication section. I won't link it as the documentation is being frequently updated now days.

As stated by the Realm Team (several times) extensive auth options are not a priority as other companies (like Firebase) handle it very well.

There were a number of posts on the Realm forums speaking to this but Ian's response to [this question](https://forums.realm.io/t/realm-cloud-half-baked-service/2547) is very succinct.

> we have and will continue to prioritize synchronization features for
>   mobile

and then

> This is why we recommend that a production app should outsource user
>   management and authentication to a company which specialized in these
>   features.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for explaining that; I had no idea I was using the old documentation! I have switched to using Firebase for authentication.